# How to track Google Ads conversions from Wpform submissions?

Tags: wordpress, google-ads-api, contact-form, contact-form-7

I have seen how to track conversions using onclick() method. But i was wondering how to work conversion code if i am using Wpform in Wordpress.

I copied the google ads conversion codes to website. But don't know how to call it. Please help.